# Tension of string-theory string

Tags: string-theory

Can the tension of a given string in string theory be increased (by say interaction with other strings), or is it always fixed.

I am trying to figure out if the energy of a string can be increased.

Thanks!

Comment: The tension of the string is a parameter of string theory. It is related to the Regge slope, $T = \frac{1}{2\pi\alpha'}$.